# Column 'idproduct' in from clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1052

I have this messy join query using 3 tables:

```
SELECT p.idproduct, p.name, m.sust, p.desc, pp.p_v
FROM products As p
LEFT JOIN meds As m ON m.idproduct = p.idproduct
NATURAL JOIN products_prices As pp
INNER JOIN suc_products As sp ON sp.idsuc = 'SUC1' AND sp.idproduct = p.idproduct
WHERE p.bars = '1';
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1052. Column 'idproduct' in from clause is ambiguous
```

Need help, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a wild guess: your `product_prices` table has an `idproduct` column and MySQL is complaining that it doesn't know if it should use `m.idproduct` or `p.idproduct` for the join.

Try changing the NATURAL JOIN to an INNER JOIN with an explicit ON condition.